# Can't print (to printer) from Python when in a web server

Tags: python, printing, subprocess

I'm able to use this code to send a job to my system printer:

```py
lpr = subprocess.Popen("/usr/bin/lpr", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)
print('printing from shell!')
lpr.stdin.write(b'print from python')
print('printed!')
```

However, if I use this code in a webserver, the code runs but the printer doesn't print.

```py
import http.server
import socketserver
import subprocess


def print_out(a,b,c):
  lpr = subprocess.Popen("/usr/bin/lpr", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)
  print('printing from shell!')
  lpr.stdin.write(b'print from python')
  print('printed!')


PORT = 8080
with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), print_out) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

This is true even if I try calling `print_out()` before creating the server (i.e., above `PORT =  8080`).

How can I make this work?

Comment: What does the call to `lpr.stdin.write` return?

Comment: `17`. Which is the length of the string I've sent to print, as far as I can tell.